# Windows phone 7 accesses SQL Azure

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm a beginner of WP7, and I spent some time looking for solutions not only can consume 
but also Insert/Update/Delete the data stored in SQL Azure.

I found a good tutorial here:

http://samidipbasu.com/2011/07/24/updating-odata-data-source-from-wp7-part-1/

However, the SQL Azure Lab no longer accepts registration.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlazurelabs/labs/odata.aspx

So, is there any other solution for directly accessing SQL Azure in the cloud without setting up a server?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey - if you intend to let the WP7-app access the SQL server directly it sounds like a rather dubious strategy, since it would mean exposing the server to anyone. You should create a web service in between and handle client authorization there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at [Windows Azure Mobile Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/), that should cover the server side.
you can then access the REST-based API from Windows Phone, see [Using Azure Mobile Services with Windows Phone](http://kenegozi.com/blog/2012/08/29/using-azure-mobile-services-with-windows-phone)